# What's the maximum of breakpoints a responsive website should have?

Tags: css, responsive, breakpoints

I was wondering if there's a maximum number of breakpoints that a website should have. Just a way of seeing ifit has too many breakpoints which I believe is not a good sign, or is it?
The website I built has 8 breakpoints. Is it bad? Should I have less?
The site is a bit complex althought I tried to gather as much code as I could that has the same characteristic, like:

CSS:

```
nav ul li, table, video, section ul, footer, .botoes, #nome, #destaque {
margin: auto;
}

nav ul li, .lista p, .smilies {
font-size: 37px;
}
```

Comment: This question is either too broad, **opinion based** or requires discussion and so is off-topic for Stack Overflow. If you have a specific, answerable, programming issue, please provide full details.

Answer (score 0):

You should just keep it simple and use as few breakpoints as possible to achieve the wanted results. There is no absolute maximum number for this, as more complex websites probably require more breakpoints.

[This](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/the-100-correct-way-to-do-css-breakpoints-88d6a5ba1862) explains good practices using breakpoints well.

Mobile-first design is something one should be aware though: Create your website for small screens first, and set breakpoints as the screen gets bigger, not the other way around. This is useful, because this way you let computers, which usually have more processing power than smartphones, handle breakpoints, and smartphones can just display the site "as is", without having to calculate large amounts of breakpoints.

[Read more about mobile first](https://en.ryte.com/wiki/Mobile_First)

Comment: I see... Thank you! :) Btw, the way I tried to gather as much code as I could that has the same characteristics, that's basically what cascade method is, right? We are suppose to do it like that, correct?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly as you should write code. There is almost never an excuse to use the same code multiple times, except perhaps in some cases for the sake of readability.